# Помогите с решением данной задачи

Tags: алгоритм, олимпиада

На сковородке одновременно можно положить `k` котлет. Каждую котлету нужно с каждой стороны обжаривать m минут непрерывно. За какое наименьшее время удастся поджарить с обеих сторон `n` котлет?

Входные данные
В единственной строке записано три натуральных числа: `k`, `m`, `n`, не превышающих `30000`.

Выходные данные
В единственную строку нужно вывести единственное число – минимальное время, за которое можно поджарить все котлеты.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, смотрите...

```
int main() {
    int k, m, n;
    cin >> k >> m >> n;
    int t;

    if (n <= k) t = 2 * m;
    else if (n * 2 % k == 0) t = m * (n * 2 / k);
    else t = m * (1 + (n * 2 / k));

    cout << t << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это какой-то определённый алгоритм ?

Comment: @Difiasham Это применение логики

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то второй if можно  заменить на `t = m * ((n * 2 + k - 1) / k);`